# Shading showing in material preview but not showing in rendered preview

Tags: rendering, shaders

I'm new to blender. I tried water shading, but the shading is showing only in material preview mode, not showing in rendered mode or in final rendering.

I have checked that it is not hidden the water objects are not disabled in the rendered view

Could anyone help me?

[image: material preview][image: rendered view] [image: water shading][image: water objects not hidden from the rendering]

Comment: Hello, the Material Preview has some HDRI images that are reflected by glass materials, whereas by default the Rendered Preview has none, so you need to give your scene an HDRI image

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Now I understand the underlying mechanism better.